# Liferay 7.2 Rest Service read headers of request

Tags: rest, request, http-headers, liferay-7, request-headers

I have Liferay 7.2.

I created a module rest.

I created a method GET

I want to read headers of incoming request.
I need to read authentication bearer token.
how can i do that?

This is my example code

```
@GET
@Path("/get-request-headers")
            
public String jsonGetRequestHeaders() throws Exception {

String authtoken = ?????;

return authtoken;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/get-request-headers")
                
    public String jsonGetRequestHeaders(
      @HeaderParam("Authorization") String token
    ) throws Exception {
    
    String authtoken = token;
    
    return authtoken;
    }
```